# Is O/R Mapping worth it?

Tags: orm

The expressiveness of the query languages (QL) provided with ORMs can be very powerful. Unfortunately, once you have a fleet of complex queries, and then some puzzling schema or data problem arises, it is very difficult to enlist the DBA help that you need? Here they are, part of the team that is evolving the database, yet they can't read the application QL, much less suggest modifications. I generally end up grabbing generated SQL out of the log for them. But then when they recommend changes to it, how does that relate to the original QL? The process is not round-trip.

So after a decade of promoting the value of ORMs, I am now wondering if I should be writing my SQL manually. And maybe all that I really want the framework to do is automate the data marshaling as much as possible.

**Question**: Have you found a way to deal with the round-trip issue in your organization? Is there a SQL-marshaling framework that scales well, and maintains easily?

(Yes, I know that pure SQL might bind me to the database vendor. But it *is* possible to write standards-compliant SQL.)

Comment: Food for thought, here is Ted Neward's extensive article "The Vietnam Of Computer Science": http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx

Comment: updated linked http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that what you want is a solution that maximizes the benefits of ORM without preventing you using other means.  We have much the same issue as you do in our application; very heavy queries, and a large data model.  Given the size of the data model, ORM is invaluable for the vast majority of the application.  It allows us to extend the data model without having to go to a great deal of effort hand-maintaining SQL scripts.  Moreover, and you touched on this, we support four database vendors, so the abstraction is nice.

However, there are instances where we've had to tune the queries manually, and since we chose a flexible ORM solution, we can do that too.  As you say, it gets out of our way when we need it gone, and simply marshals objects for us.

So, in short (yep, short) yes, ORM is worth it, but like every solution to a problem, it's not a panacea.

Answer (score 7):

In general, ORMs increase developer productivity a lot so I'd using them unless they've become a bigger problem than they're worth. If a majority of your tables are big enough that you are having a lot of problems, consider ditching the ORM. I would definitely not say that ORMs are a bad idea in general. Most databases are small enough and most queries are simple enough that they work well.

I've overcome that problem by using stored procedures or hand-written SQL only for the poorly performing queries. DBAs love stored procedures because they can modify them without telling you. Most (if not all) ORMs allow you to mix in hand written SQL or stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

todays O/R frameworks, as i believe you're familiar with, support the option of defining some queries manually ((N)Hibernate does). that can be used for complex parts of schemas, and for straight-forward parts use the ORM as provided by the framework.

another thing for you to check out might be the iBatis framework (http://ibatis.apache.org/). i haven't used it, but i've read that it's more close to SQL and people familiar with databases and SQL prefer it over full-blown ORM framework like hibernate, because it's closer to them than the completely different concept of ORM.